# How to make print option to print a particular activity through printer in Android Studio

Tags: android, printing, tablet, profile

I need your help about print options I will give clear explanation what I need exactly so let me know if its possible or not.

per suppose I have 3 activities in my android app

first screen

some user data was there

like name : abc
     age  : 36
     education: B Tech

So above data have one activity

So I need to print those information through any printer(based on availability)

So needs to come those data in paper without android tool bar (top )

So is there any possibilities are there to achieve this

may be I will use android phone/tablet

Is it possible or not?

If its possible provide solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you @Nitish sir

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

The easiest way to do it is to make HTML Document and print it using Android Printing Framework like discribed [here](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html#load-html).

Comment: you mean activity data needs to convert html document then will give print

Comment: Yes, convert your data to HTML document, which may be printed by Android.